# Queue containing fixed-size arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, queue

I'm using a `queue<vector<int> >` in a computationally intensive search algorithm written in C++. I'd like to replace this data structure with a queue or similar FIFO structure that contains fixed-size arrays. **How can I do this in C++?**

The motivation for this replacement is decreasing runtime. While profiling I've noticed quite a bit of time spent on creating and adding things to vectors. I've replaced a few critical vectors with fixed-size arrays and measured 20-50% runtime decreases. Hence I'd like to replace the vectors in the FIFO data structure above. Note all the code in question is part of the inner-most loops hence the non-trivial decreases in runtime.

Comment: I cannot see how making a queue of fixed size arrays could help, Vectors can be cheaply swapped and moved, arrays can't.

Comment: Not this hasn't perhaps crossed your mind, but have you considered using the default-container for a queue-adapter, namely a **std::deque<>** ?

Comment: Just curious, but did you profile in debug?  `vector` is *slow* in debug.  @juanchopanza really, the OP should be thinking about `std::unique_ptr< std::array<  int, 10 > >`, which gives you fast-move with most of the advantages of a fixed size buffer, if it turns out that this `std::vector` is actually a problem.

Comment: @Yakk I believe I'm profiling in Release mode since I updated the appropriate entry in the Xcode scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `std::queue<std::array<int, N> >` to give you specifically what you're asking for. A queue where each element is a fixed-size array.

Alternatively, you could store the actual data in a buffer outside the queue, and just store pointers/iterators pointing into the buffer.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<std::array<int,N>>` will have modest indirection costs compared to `std::array<int,N>`, but much much faster `move` speeds for modest sized `N` or larger.

Comment: True. It'll also perform very similarly to a `queue<vector<int>>` which he has now. But yeah, worth pointing out that alternative as well

Comment: It blocks needless copies.  And avoids requiring `reserve` which could explain the performance problems.